# Associated equivariant holomorphic map from a surface group representation

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Given a (smooth but not holomorphic) surface bundle over surface $S_g\to M\to S_h$ (where $g,h>1$, there is an induced surface group representation
$$\pi_1(S_h)\to \text{SP}(2g,\mathbb R).$$

I was told that there is an associated equivariant holomorphic map
$$\tilde{S_h}=\mathbb H^2\to \text{SP}(2g,\mathbb R)/U(g).$$

I wonder why there is such an equivariant holomorphic map and is it generally true that if we have a homomorphism between lattices, then there is an associated equivariant map between their symmetric spaces? Here I see ${S_h}$ as a Fuchsian group and $\tilde{S_h}$ is its symmetric space, and $\text{SP}(2g,\mathbb R)/U(g)$ is the symmetric space of $\text{SP}(2g,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "a surface bundle?" Do you mean a holomorphic fiber bundle or a smooth fiber bundle? Also, how much Teichmuller theory do you know? Do yoy know about the period map?

Comment: @MoisheKohan just a smooth fiber bundle. I have limited knowledge on Teichmuller theory and period map

Comment: Then whoever told you about existence of an equivariant holomorphic map was wrong. Why do you believe them? Ask them about details.

Comment: @MoisheKohan could you please explain why it's wrong

Comment: Take the bundle associated with the action of $\pi_1(S_h)$ on $S_g$ which is given by a cyclic subgroup of $Diff(S_g)$ whose image in $Sp(2g,Z)$ is real-diagonalizable  and nontrivial. Most likely, you misunderstood what you have been told about surface bundles.